# How to fix conversion error in MVC2 dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I tried simple dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC2 but got error below from tryupdatemodel.

How to fix this, everthing looks correct ?

view:

```
   <%= Html.DropDownList("Post24DeliveryPlaces", Model.DeliveryPlace)%>
```

model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Post24DeliveryPlaces { get; set; }

public string DeliveryPlace { get; set; }
```

result:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.  

at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)  

 at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.UnwrapPossibleArrayType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)  

at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(Type type, CultureInfo culture)   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.ConvertProviderResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState, String modelStateKey, ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult, Type destinationType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your html input is being named Post24DeliveryPlaces and it's trying to bind a single string to that.

The Post data is looking like this:

```
POST
{
    Post24DeliveryPlaces = (string)
}
```

However, in your model, Post24DeliveryPlaces is an IEnumerable and it can't convert at string to SelectListItem.

`Html.DropDownList` takes the field name as the first parameter.  Try changing to this, giving the list of delivery places as the second parameter.

```
Html.DropDownList("DeliveryPlace", Model.Post24DeliveryPlaces)
```

This will generate the Html

```
<select name="DeliveryPlace">
    <option value="..">....</option>
    ....
</select>
```