# ModelState is always invalid when Dropdownlist is on ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this ViewModel:

```
public class CreateUserModel {
  public int StateId { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, Model.States, "--select state--")
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model= new CreateUserModel();
    model.States = new SelectList(_context.States.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateUserModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Users.Add(new User()
        {
          StateId = model.StateId
        });
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

This error makes ModelState invalid:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type
>   'System.String' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' failed because
>   no type converter can convert between these types.

---

**Edited to include my complete view**:

```
@model AgreementsAndAwardsDB.ViewModels.CreateUserModel

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
       </head>
    <body class="createPage">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Accounts", Model, FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.DropDownList("StateId", Model.States)
            <input type="submit" />
        }
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you show the line where things go south?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495206/mvc3-dropdown-model-state-error-on-httppost and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218011/how-to-fix-conversion-error-in-mvc2-dropdownlist

Comment: The case of mine is different because I have the right form of razor syntax: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, Model.States, "--select state--")

Comment: Can you please post the entire code of your view? Also, please check the code for the non-post `Create` method, since you name your model variable `model` but then refer to something called `createUserModel` to set the list of states.

Comment: I noticed that the States field is getting error because it is in ModelState.Values, and the attempted value for the field is a String that why I'm getting error. How can I remove it to the ModelState.Values?

Comment: States shouldn't be in ModelState.Values because it is not a validated property, it is just store data when I pass view model from controller to view

Comment: You still haven't posted the whole view. If the only thing in your form is the `DropDownListFor` for the `StateId` property then States won't be in the `ModelState.Keys`. The code you have posted works, and there must be an error in your view (which you don't show us) if it doesn't work.

Comment: In the meantime, I am using Model["States"].Errors.Clear() to make my Model valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing your model as route values to the form action using this line:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Accounts", Model, FormMethod.Post))
```

Since the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States` can't be parsed in a good way for querystrings, the form action will be `Accounts/Create?StateId=0&States=System.Web.Mvc.SelectList` and the model binder will try to bind the string **"System.Web.Mvc.SelectList"** to an `IEnumerable<>`, which is why your code doesn't work.

You would probably be OK with just

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

, but if you want to specify action, controller and method go for

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Accounts", FormMethod.Post))
```